# Is it good idea to build own XML Schemas for purpose of validation not our XMLs?

Tags: xml, xsd

We are developing a price comparison service. We are importing a lot of data from over 50 shops. Each shop usually uses a different XML format for describing their offer.

Unfortunately, sometimes a specific shop forgets to notify us about changes which are introduced to their XML. Which of course causes problems, or even worse... sometimes specific shop introduce new fields in XML (requested by us) and forget to notify us that it is ready.

Is it a good idea to build our own XML Schema for XML from each shop, and validate those XML against XML Schemas during every update?

Comment: Writing over 50 schemas? Is that what you mean? Writing XML Schemas is a good idea of course - but maintaining 50 Schemas might be more complex than figuring out the changes by hand. Tell us more about the frequency of changes to the XML structures.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Very hard to say... Data in each XML are updated every few hours, format of XML usually stay intact by (on average) 4-6 weeks. 50 shops are now, we should double number of shops within few next month... so we are wondering what will easily scale.

Comment: Why can't each shop produce a schema that validates the data it sends? If **I** were producing the data, I'd want to validate it to know that I'm not sending out garbage.

Comment: @Louis I am sure, some shops will do that, unfortunately knowing from experience, asking few shops about that will be bureaucratic nightmare.

Comment: By the way,the [xml-schema] tag covers XML Schema, Relax NG, DTD, SOX, etc. but you mention only "XML Schema" in your question, which would imply that [xsd] is the correct tag for your question.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear: You are asking about writing more than 50 (potentially 100) XML Schemas to control XML data you get from individual shops, right?

You are right that this (i.e. restricting XML content) is what XML Schema is inherently good at. It's just that XML Schema

- is verbose and it can take some time to get the tiny details right (for example, specifying how many times an element can occur or which specific strings you allow as content). Also, maintenance can be painstaking.
- is mainly intended for fixed XML formats - which is the reason you write a Schema in the first place. XML structures that change on a regular basis every 4 to 6 weeks (as you say in your post) are rather dynamic, in my opinion.

Besides, it is clearly not enough to alter the Schema if your XML data undergoes a structural change. It is also the *processing* of new XML structures that would need your attention every 4 weeks - a hundredfold enterprise.

---

To sum up, no, this is a bad idea because of the frequency of changes and the number of individual XML formats you process. Getting the shops to standardize the XML content they send you might be a bureaucratic nightmare - but less of a nightmare than dealing with ever-changing and unpredictable XML structures.

Having said all this, let me add another crucial factor: size of XML documents. I have written this answer assuming that you are processing large XML files. However, if the XML files consist of, say, 3 elements each, the Schema approach becomes more feasible again.

Comment: Each XML usually contain thousands of "records" and each record has only 10-20 attributes/sub elements.

Comment: Well, then I'll stick to the answer I have given.